# Bigcommerce API PHP creating order with options

Tags: php, bigcommerce

The following code successfully creates order.
The item with id "3889" has three sizes: "7", "8", "9".
But this item added to an order does not have the passed size "7".
In result size just not specified.
No errors from Bigcommerce.

[image: pic how it looks in admin panel]

Question: How to pass the size for the product to the order?

```
<?php
require 'C:\wamp64\www\bigcommerceDemo\vendor\autoload.php';
require 'C:\wamp64\www\bigcommerceDemo\bg_api_connection\scripting.php';

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$first_name = "example";
$last_name = "example";
$company = "";
$street_1 = "example";
$street_2 = "";
$city = "example";
$state = "example";
$zip = "example";
$country = "United States";
$country_iso2 = "";
$phone = "example";
$email = "example";

$object = array(
    "customer_id" => "12610",
    "status_id" => "7",
    "date_created" => "Mon, 11 Sep 2017 19:26:23 +0000",
       "billing_address" => array(
        "first_name" => $first_name,
        "last_name" => $last_name,
        "company" => $company,
        "street_1" => $street_1,
        "street_2" => $street_2,
        "city" => $city,
        "state" => $state,
        "zip" => $zip,
        "country" => $country,
        "phone" => $phone,
        "email" => $email),
        "products" => array(
            0 => array(
              "product_id" => 3889,
              "quantity"   => 1,
              "product_options" => array(
                0 => array(
                    "id" => 1267,
                    "value" => 7
                  )
              )
            ),
            1 => array(
              "product_id" => 15805,
              "quantity"   => 1,
            )
          )
    );
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct `id` value for product options?

Comment: @ProEvilz it's how I did it: I added item with id "3889" to an order manually, using Admin Panel. Then I request product options info from this order. And I got array with all ids:  [id] => 7178
                                    [option_id] => 1240
                                    [order_product_id] => 9939
                                    [product_option_id] => 1267
                                    [display_name] => Size
                                    [display_value] => Silver
                                    [value] => 7. 
I tried other IDs. Got BG error.

Answer (score 0):

ID Value of the option was wrong!
And it was giving instead size 7, the word "Silver".
Because [display_value] => Silver. This info I got from the order.

The following code getting **id** of the product option (not the option itself) and the **value** of the option (not the product):

```
$product_options_array = Bigcommerce::getProductOptions($product_id);
$product_option_id_array = array_map(create_function('$id', 'return $id->id;'), $product_options_array);
$product_option_id = implode(" ", $product_option_id_array);//in "product_options" => array it goes to "id" => 1267

$product_one_option_values_array = Bigcommerce::getOption($product_option_id);
$values_array = $product_one_option_values_array->values;
$value_label_array = array_map(create_function('$value', 'return $value->value;'), $values_array);
$value_id_array = array_map(create_function('$id', 'return $id->id;'), $values_array);//in "product_options" => array it goes to "value" => 4975
```